# Передача аргумента в декораторы

Tags: python-3.x, декоратор

Суть задачи в том, что мне нужно введенное слово передать в decorator, если слово есть в stringed, написать, что оно запрещено, если оно отсутствует, передать значение выше в checking_for_vowels.

Если я делаю

```
def decorator(var):
  def wrap():
    if var() in stringed:
      wrap()
    else:
      return var()
  return wrap
```

При введении отсутствующего в stringed слова, приходится вводить дважды, ибо срабатывает var(). Как мне передать выше аргумент и проверить слово на вхождение в список?

[image: Decorators python]

[Ссылка на полный код](https://repl.it/@DatoAkobia/NoxiousFussyResource)

Весь код

```
censor = ["hate, damn"]
vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u')

stringed = "".join(str(i) for i in censor).split()

def checking_for_vowels(words):
  def wrapped():
    vowels_count = 0
    for i in words():
      if i.isnumeric():
        continue
      elif i in vowels:
        vowels_count += 1
    return str(vowels_count) + " Vowels Found"
  return wrapped

def decorator(var):
  def wrap():
    if var() in stringed:
      wrap()
    else:
      return var()
  return wrap

@checking_for_vowels
@decorator
def main():
  a = input("Enter word ")
  return a
print(main())
```

Comment: для тех, кто прикладывает код картинками, есть отдельный котел в аду)

Comment: лучше вставьте код вместо картинки.

Comment: почитайте это https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/dekoratory.html

Comment: @Viktorov, отдельный котел - это VIP версия? ;)

Comment: Прикрепил ссылку на полный код.

Comment: Котел для тех, кто прикладывает ссылку на код вместо самого кода, там недалеко.

Comment: А сейчас что будет? Котел для тех, кто прикладывает код?

Прикрепил весь код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, под эту задачу отлично подойдет паттерн [Цепочка обязанностей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9), но и через декораторы можно сделать его подобие.

Нужно только передавать состояние, чтобы знать когда декоратор должен остановиться:

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
CENSOR = ["hate", "damn"]

def checking_for_vowels(func):
    def wrapped():
        ok, text = func()
        if not ok:
            return text

        vowels_count = 0
        for i in text:
            if i in VOWELS:
                vowels_count += 1
        return f"{vowels_count} Vowels Found"

    return wrapped

def decorator(func):
    def wrap():
        text = func()

        if text in CENSOR:
            print(f'Слово "{text}" запрещено')
            return False, text
        else:
            return True, text

    return wrap

@checking_for_vowels
@decorator
def main():
    a = input("Enter word ")
    return a

print(main())
```

---

**PS.** очень простой пример цепочки обязанностей:

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
CENSOR = ["hate", "damn"]

def checking_for_vowels(text):
    vowels_count = 0
    for i in text:
        if i in VOWELS:
            vowels_count += 1

    print(f"{vowels_count} Vowels Found")

def check_censor(text):
    if text in CENSOR:
        print(f'Слово "{text}" запрещено')
        return False
    else:
        return True

def main():
    a = input("Enter word ")
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = main()

    for check_func in [check_censor, checking_for_vowels]:
        ok = check_func(text)
        if not ok:
            break
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Если честно, впервые вижу присваивание по типу ok, text = func()

Можно ссылку на ресурс с такой информацией?

Comment: @QualcommAtheros, это просто распаковка кортежа -- `return True, text` вернул кортеж (tuple), т.е. `(True, text)`, а `ok, text = (True, text)` соответственно положил в `ok=True`, `text=text`. Так можно распаковывать списки, строки

Comment: Можно было и без декораторов да, но задание было строго на декораторы, а я не разобрался в одном моменте, спасибо еще раз.